# How to protect attributes in Rails 4 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Let's say I have the `User` model. In it I have attributes that I want visible within the app, but whenever I send this data to a client (the Rails app will be an API), some properties of the `User` will automatically hidden in the object so won't be sent via the ajax call. For instance:

`user = User.create({ name:'Name', email:'email@email.com', secret:'secret' })`

Internally, I want to be able to update the secret model normally, however when I do send the user to via ajax, the `secret` attribute won't be visible.

How can I achieve this using Rails 4 (NOT using ActiveRecord but Mongoid instead)?

Comment: How about `render json: user.as_json(except: [:secret])` ?

Comment: That's an option but I'd prefer something I could do on the `model` level as this will happen in quite a few models and in many controllers.

Comment: If you want this at the model level, you could (re)define the `as_json` method in your model with the conditions you require.

Comment: I'd prefer to use jbuilder https://github.com/rails/jbuilder for views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redefine the`as_json` method on your model.

```
class User
  BLACKLISTED_ATTRIBUTES = [
    :secret,
    :another_secret,
    :super_secret_stuff,
  ]

  def as_json(options = {})    
    options ||= {}
    options[:except] ||= []
    options[:except] |= BLACKLISTED_ATTRIBUTES
    super(options)
  end
end
```

That way your model will always remove the blacklisted attributes when anything calls `as_json`.